# How can I get git to use graphical diff locally and textual diff over ssh?

Tags: git, git-diff

I've configured git to use meld as the difftool, but I sometimes need to see textual diffs when working over SSH. Is there any way to configure git so that it uses the proper diff tool for the environment?

My current .gitconfig:

```
[diff]
        external = meld
        tool = meld
[merge]
        external = meld
        tool = meld
[difftool]
        prompt = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a differ that checks the environment and invokes the right diff engine and put that in your config.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer. If I do, I'll put a link to it on here somewhere.

Comment: I never did, and I've been too lazy to write a diff wrapper that checks the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question as I'm not sure of your environment, but when I set up meld as the difftool, `git difftool` invokes it as expected, but `git diff` does a normal textual diff. I'm not sure why, given my `.gitconfig`...:

```
[diff]
  tool = meld
[difftool]
  prompt = false
[difftool "meld"]
  #trustExitCode = true
  #cmd = open -W -a Meld --args \"$LOCAL\" \"$PWD/$REMOTE\"
  cmd = meld "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
```